# How can I determine the actual timezone the user is in?

Tags: apex, visualforce, timezone

I can easily pull the user records timezone field but what if the user is traveling and not in that timezone today. Is there a way to determine what timezone they are accessing salesforce from?

Answer (score 1):

In Visualforce, or a Aura/LWC component, you could use some code *on the client* to determine time zone, and then send it to the server. In Visualforce:

```
<apex:form id="form>
  <script>
  window.addEventListener('onload', function() {
    setTimeZone(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
  });
  </script>
  <apex:actionFunction name="setTimeZone" reRender="form" action="{!setCurrentTimeZone}">
    <apex:param name="tz" value="" assignTo="{!timeZoneString}" />
  </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
```

Without some UI to detect the client time zone, you'd be left mapping their IPv4 or IPv6 address to a country/state/city, and then mapping that to a time zone. This isn't impossible, but would represent a lot of work to make it just right.